# Flask route to a variable url

Tags: html, flask, routes

I want to be able to route to a specific user's profile using flask as a web server but the user's profile name will be different so how would implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is surrounded by square brackets in the URL and passed to the view function as a regular parameter.

Assuming you have a template called `profile.html` and want to pass user data to that template from function `getUser`, your route would look like this:

```
@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile(username):
    return render_template('profile.html', user = getUser(username))
```

Comment: < > – guillemets, inequality signs, pointy brackets, or brackets. Sometimes referred to as angle brackets, in such cases as HTML markup. Occasionally known as broken brackets or "brokets".
not square brackets!